# How to get number (count) of comments from comment table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a news and comment system where I want to see the number of comments for a particular news item. I tried many ways but most of them show me the number of all comments in the table but not the number of specific news. How should this be done?

I have table comments with id , nid(news id) comment and author.i tried this method but it shows me the number of all comments from the whole table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY nid";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$numberOfComments = $stmt->rowCount();
echo "(<a href=\"comments.php?id=".$id."\">Add Comment</a>) <hr> Comments ( ".$numberOfComments." )";
```

There is my SQL file comments.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`c_title` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`c_author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`comment` text NOT NULL,
`dateAdded` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `nid`, `c_title`, `c_author`,  `comment`,`dateAdded`) 
VALUES(1, 1, 'My 1st comment', 'User', '1st comment text', '14/08/2019 ,   10:55:32'), 
(2, 1, 'My 2nd comment', 'Admin', '2nd comment here', '14/08/2019 ,  10:56:58'),
(3, 2, 'Comment test here', 'User', 'Comment test here', '14/08/2019 ,10:57:10');
```

In this case, I have a product to which I add a comment. I want to know how many comments each product has but I can't handle it. "nid" is my product ID.

Comment: Do you know how to use a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  count the rows  return you could use proper sql function

you can use count(*)  and group by

for single news_id

```
 SELECT count(*) my_count
 FROM comments 
 WHERE nid = 1
```

for all  new_id  you coudl use

```
 SELECT nid, count(*) my_count
 FROM comments 
 GROUP BY nid
```

Comment: Doesn't work. By the first way for any news item shows me there is 1 comment and the second way shows me that there are 2 comments.
Actually in the first news I have 2 comments in the table and in the second 1

Comment: if think you should check better for the result  .. the first query retun just one row  and you must inspect the my_count column alias for read the number of the row .. the second  query return two rows with two column the first column is the nid  and the second  the number of comments rows  for this nid .. answer  updated  for  column name alias

Comment: Currently it shows me that there is 1 comment and 2 news. What exactly does 'my_count' do. I can't figure out how to show how many comments there are on the news, I don't understand much.

Comment: update your question  .. add  a valid data sample as  text  ..  so we can't try to explain  how count(*) work ..

Comment: It's done. Can someone help ?